# How are high-speed circuits tested if test equipment doesnt exist?

Tags: rf, measurement, testing, frequency-measurement

How was testing done for Ghz to THz range circuits and devices before fast enough scopes and frequency counters existed?

Comment: "No measurement equipment is capable of signal measurement at these ranges." Where did you get that idea? Here's a high frequency scope: http://teledynelecroy.com/100ghz/ A few seconds with google reveal innumerable pages on mmwave measurements.

Comment: Ok, but lets go to a higher speed then, how do you verify the operation and diagnose it if it fails if measurement equipment doesn't exist? Surely there were Ghz circuits before Ghz scopes and even Ghz frequency counters.

Comment: That's not a helpful comment,

Comment: This is an interesting question, since it touches one of those issues that seems like a classic chicken-and-egg problem, often recurring in bleeding edge-engineering. I hope to see some interesting answers.

Comment: Trial and error is a accepted method - but expensive...

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Eggs predate the chicken by thousands of years. Reptiles and fish laid eggs before birds flew and chickens in particular even existed.

Comment: One answer is to build your own specialist apparatus to detect whatever you need; an example I like quoting is http://www.electronicdesign.com/test-amp-measurement/whats-all-femtoampere-stuff-anyhow

Comment: A frequency counter is not the only method for high frequency measurement. The first microwave magnetron was build and tested many years before frequency counters for microwaves existed. [Lecher lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lecher_lines) were used for frequency measurement. Not very precise, but with a resolution better than centimeters of wavelength.

Answer (score 6):

For some perspective, consider that optical signals are still too high frequency for the instantaneous electric field to be sampled and measured, but there are still lots of different kinds of measurements we can do on an optical signal.

- With a power sensor (a photodiode or even an LDR) we can measure the power of the signal.
- With a prism or diffraction grating we can build a spectrometer and get a rough idea of the signal's spectrum and/or pulsewidth.
- With an interferometer we can mix the optical signal with a delayed version of itself and measure the coherence time (bandwidth) of the signal with perhaps gigahertz resolution.
- With a tunable local oscillator (laser), we can even down-mix the signal and measure its spectrum with an RF spectrum analyzer, getting 100's of kHz resolution.

All of these measurements have analogs in the microwave regime and were or could be used by microwave engineers prior to the advent of multi-gigahertz oscilloscopes.

Answer (score 5):

Long ago they relied of the speed of Gunn diodes for sampling the input signal waveform with a control pulse duration so that the difference frequency could be displayed on a slow timebase oscilloscope. If the sample duration was short enough to capture only the point on a recurring waveform the the waveform was preserved.

Gunn diodes were useful since they had low negative resistance so once triggered, that would accelerate then hold the result once the bias charge was depleted.

The key to reception of a frequency higher than can be observed or detected is to use imaging down-conversion to a useful IF frequency  or direct to base band depends on the conversion efficiency, power level and SNR.

Methods such as  interferometry, Diode detectors, pulsed samplers, where the harmonic of the sampling rate has sufficient harmonic energy in the band of interest.

Nonlinear mixers such as; "high temp" step-edge Josephson junction, varicaps, GaAs diodes and heterobarrier varactors (HBV) or optical pump with extreme fast rise times from small inert gas arc gaps.

These aliasing down-conversion type scopes were called [Sampling oscilloscopes.](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwizz8zXj6LYAhUI9YMKHUPNDx8QFgg1MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tek.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fmedia%2Fmedia%2Fresources%2FSampling%2520Oscilloscope%2520Techniques.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0VBVJ0Q8Y1ZIra0eQKAAlD)   ( but  only useful for repetitive waves) 
[image]

[further reading](https://www.google.ca/search?client=firefox-b&dcr=0&ei=b1g_Ws6RDIepjwTU_LOADQ&q=Gunn%20diodes%20sampling%20oscilloscope&oq=Gunn%20diodes%20sampling%20oscilloscope&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2548.7199.0.7419.22.22.0.0.0.0.152.2056.12j8.20.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.16.1674...0j0i22i30k1j33i160k1j33i21k1.0.TAjHEyTkFZk)

Comment: This is interesting and explains how it works, I suppose you can see if it's working right, but can it be used to reconstruct broken  waveforms? Seems challenging.

Comment: @FourierFlux, it certain can be used to reconstruct a waveform. The Keysight 86100 series sample at 40 kSa/s, but can reconstruct signals with bandwidth to 80 GHz.

Comment: How though? You only sample a finite number of points and without some constraints on the input waveform you can't really say anything.

Answer (score 1):

'Fast enough' oscilloscopes are a trick for displaying signals that
vary in time, but they aren't the only trick.   A 1 GHz oscillator,
for example, will heat a resistor.    It will also resonate
with a cavity length of about 120mm (which can be determined
by sensing the heating of resistors).   The combination is called a 'wavemeter'.

A crude wavemeter is a length of wire placed on a paper plate, in 
a microwave oven.   The (about two inch) right length of wire
gets much hotter, and scorches the plate to a darker color, than
other wire lengths.

You can tell the frequency, without a
'frequency counter', of light by using a diffraction grating
(a blank CDROM has 1 hour playing time, at 1 revolution per second,
so you can measure the band with a ruler and use it to diffract a 
laser beam...) and measure the wavelength, thus (knowing the
speed of light) the frequency.

If you have a non-sine-wave, the various harmonics will ALL show
up, and with a little care in measurement one can identify square
and triangle waves.

Most people wouldn't call that CD blank a 'measuring instrument',
but it does the job.   It just isn't convenient and precalibrated.
Neither is the paper plate in the microwave oven (and if you value
the flavor of your food, you need to clean out smoky byproducts).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to analyzed terrahertz device so long one is not too interested in the precise time domain information. You can always use a mixer/downconver, and perform digitization, and analysis on frequency domain.

A company call [Virginia Diode](https://www.vadiodes.com/en/) produce such mixer.